# $C_p$ vs $C_v$ thermodynamics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy

Why is $c_p$ used in the following problem when the ball volume is a constant?

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specific heat for a solid at constant volume is essentially the same as that at constant pressure. That is because solids are generally considered incompressible. For this reason the specific heat for a solid is generally given as a single value, sometimes simply written as is $c$ or $c_p$. If you look up the specific heat for aluminum, you will usually only find one value. On the Engineering Toolbox web site its listed as 0.91 kJ/kg K.

For gases two specific heats are given, $c_p$ and $c_v$, because gases are highly compressible.

Hope this helps.